# netcool omnibus probe rules

Tags: tivoli

I have following probable values for $6 coming to netcool omnibus rules.
I would like to extract the InstanceName  from $6

```
Eg: SQLSERVER1
SQL2012TESTRTM
SQL2012TESTSTD1
SQL2014STD
MSSQLSERVER
```

Below are $6 values

```
6 = "Microsoft.SQLServer.DBEngine:TM-B33F-FAD4.cap.dev.net;SQLSERVER1:1"
6  = "Microsoft.SQLServer.2012.Agent:TM-B33F-FAD4.cap.dev.net;SQL2012TESTRTM;SQLAgent$SQL2012TESTRTM:1"
6 = "Microsoft.SQLServer.2012.Agent:TM-B33F-FAD4.cap.dev.net;SQL2012TESTRTM;SQLAgent$SQL2012TESTRTM:1"
6 = "Microsoft.SQLServer.2012.Agent:TM-B33F-FAD4.cap.dev.net;SQL2012TESTSTD1;SQLAgent$SQL2012TESTSTD1:1"
6 = "Microsoft.SQLServer.Database:TM-B33F-FAD4.cap.dev.net;SQL2012TESTSTD1;DB2:1"
6 = "Microsoft.SQLServer.2012.Agent:TM-B33F-FAD4.cap.dev.net;SQL2012TESTRTM;SQLAgent$SQL2012TESTRTM:1"
6 = "Microsoft.SQLServer.2014.Agent:TM-B33F-FAD4.cap.dev.net;SQL2014STD;SQLAgent$SQL2014STD:1"
6 = "Microsoft.SQLServer.Database:TM-B33F-FAD4.cap.dev.net;SQL2012TESTSTD1;DB2:1"
6 = "Microsoft.SQLServer.2014.DBEngine:TM-B33F-FAD4.cap.dev.net;SQL2014STD:1"
6 = "Microsoft.SQLServer.Database:TM-B33F-FAD4.cap.dev.net;SQL2012TESTSTD1;DB2:1"
6 = "Microsoft.SQLServer.2014.Agent:TM-B33F-FAD4.cap.dev.net;SQL2014STD;SQLAgent$SQL2014STD:1"
6 = "Microsoft.SQLServer.Database:TM-B33F-FAD4.cap.dev.net;SQL2012TURKSTD1;DB1:1"

6 = "Microsoft.SQLServer.2014.DBFile:CTNTV01;MSSQLSERVER;SPOT;1;35:1"

6 = "Microsoft.SQLServer.Library.EventLogCollectionTarget:TM-B33F-FAD4.cap.dev.net:1"
```

I have tried below code to extract, it works for most of them above.

```
            @temp = extract($6, ";([^\:]+)\:")
            if (regmatch(@temp, "[\;]"))
            {
                    @temp = extract(@temp, "([^\:]+)\;")
            }
```

But it does not work for

```
Microsoft.SQLServer.2014.DBFile:CTNTV01;MSSQLSERVER;SPOT;1;35:1
```

I believe the second extract inside if statement needs to be corrected little more.
It extracts until `MSSQLSERVER;SPOT;1,` however I only want `MSSQLSERVER` from it.

Can you please help in correcting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below.

```
@temp = extract($6, ";([^\:]+)\:")
        if (regmatch(@temp, "[\;]"))
        {
                @temp = extract(@temp, "([^\;]+)\;")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpQ2Q.png
Made changes in the if "([A-Z]+)[A-Z0-9:;]+"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).